# Replace Notification Caused by Android Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, android-wake-lock

I created a Notification for my app which gets displayed when the app runs in the background but I also get a Notification from **Android System** with the title **MyAppName is using battery**. I only want my Notification to be shown. How can I disable or replace the default notification when an app is run in the background.

I have a `Class MyClass extends Service implements SensorEventListener, LocationListener {...}` in which I record sensor and gps data. I create an `ExecutorService`, which  each time `onSensorChanged(...)` is triggered which does some stuff.

I also have a `PowerManager.WakeLock` so that the service runs in the background.

Comment: you cannot disable this. It is a warning from the OS to the user that your app is draining the battery.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I wanted to make sure the user understands why the battery is drained so he doesn't just kills the app.

Comment: Use a foreground service